# Eliminate SORT operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-execution-plan

Scratching my head on this one. I've tested a couple of different indexes and can't seem to get rid of this sort operator. It's 53% of the cost on over 5 million rows. It's taking quite a while to run, so I'm hoping an index might help out.

Query:

```
select  Client_ID
      , first_value(LOB_Code) over(partition by Service_VisitID order by member_dim_key desc)           as LOB_Code
      , MMI 
      , Service_Date
      , Service_YearMonth
      , Service_Billing_Provider_ID
      , isnull(Service_Billing_Provider_TIN,'') as service_Billing_Provider_TIN
      , Service_Rendering_Provider_ID               
      , isnull(Service_Rendering_Provider_TIN,'') as Service_Rendering_Provider_TIN
      , Service_Key
      , Diagnosis_Group_Key
      , Service_VisitID
      , NPI
      , row_number() over(partition by Service_VisitID order by service_total_paid_amt desc) as Row_N
from #SpecAttrib
```

I created an index on Service_VisitID and Member_Dim_Key which eliminated a problem sort and thought the same strategy would work for this one.

I've tried the following two - the first I expected to work, and the second just for the hell of it:

```
create nonclustered index ix_specattrib_visit_paid on #specAttrib ([Service_VisitID] asc,[Service_Total_Paid_amt] desc)

create nonclustered index ix_specattrib_visit_paid on #specAttrib ([Service_Total_Paid_amt] desc, [Service_VisitID] asc)
```

Here are the properties of the sort operator.

[image]

Comment: So this sort comes from your Row Number windowing function, which must be done to achieve the results you want to see. Can you add a `WHERE` clause to reduce the total rows searched?

Comment: Yeah, I figured that was the source of the sort, but I thought maybe an index would help. Unfortunately, I can't limit the number of rows any further. In fact, the last step to getting to the smallest set is this row_number() function. Any suggestions for a more efficient method?

Comment: Is the row number being used for something?